# Что значит слово `прикладной` в - http это протокол прикладного уровня?

Tags: http

Что значит слово `прикладной` в - http это протокол прикладного уровня?

Хочу понять, именно разжевать, везде написано много слов с использованием этого слова, но хотелось бы больше ясности что вкладывают в это слово

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI

Answer (score 1):

Если совсем формально, то в самом http (Hypertext Transfer Protocol) нет слова "прикладной". Но да, это протокол прикладного уровня. Я бы подчеркнул, что это не прикладной уровень модели OSI, а прикладной уровень модели TCP/IP, который фактически объединяет прикладной уровень, уровень представления и сеансовый уровень модели OSI. Хотя русскоязычная wikipedia относит http к прикладному уровню модели OSI.

На базе англоязычной части wikipedia (русскозячная статья хуже) отмечу:

Прикладной уровень включает в себя протоколы, используемые большинством приложений для предоставления пользовательских услуг или обмена данными приложений по сетевым соединениям, установленным протоколами более низкого уровня. Он может включать в себя некоторые основные службы поддержки сети, такие как протоколы маршрутизации и конфигурация хоста. Также замечу, что хотя приложения обычно знают о ключевых качествах соединения транспортного уровня, таких как IP-адреса конечных точек и номера портов, протоколы прикладного уровня обычно рассматривают протоколы транспортного уровня (и ниже) как черные ящики, которые обеспечивают стабильное сетевое соединение, через которое можно обмениваться данными. Транспортный уровень и более низкие уровни не связаны со спецификой протоколов прикладного уровня.

Подробнее:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite

Comment: Eсли ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).

Comment: В этом ответе я не вижу ответа на мой вопрос) что значит протокол "Прикладного" уровня? Скажем так, меня не интересует что такое Http, мне хочется понять что такое протокол "Прикладного" уровня

Comment: Вся вторая часть ответа этому протоколу посвящена (со слов "Прикладной уровень"). Но тогда вам более детально про модели OSI и TCP/IP лучше читать, например, в wikipedia - советую сразу со всеми уровнями ознакомиться, это и полезно и станет понятнее, чем от них прикладной отличается. <https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI> и <https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP>